# Science fiction story or novel where alien plant erupts from under ice

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space-exploration

I was told about a science fiction story in which humans have landed on an ice-covered planet or moon and a gigantic plantlike organism bursts out from under the ice due to the humans' lights stimulating its flowering, or something like that.  The humans' landing party is destroyed; I think the story is told by the lone survivor.  Any idea what this might be?

Answer (score 24):

This is the Chinese ship Tsien landing on Europa in [*2010: Odyssey Two*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AHG4DUK) by Arthur C. Clarke.

Chapter 11, *Ice and Vacuum:*

> Perhaps it's a phototrope, its biological cyce triggered by the
>   sunlight that filters through the ice. Or it could have been attracted
>   like a moth to a candle. Our floodlights must have been more
>   brilliant than anything that Europa has ever known.

and later...

> 'This is professor Chang on Europa, reporting the destruction of
>   spaceship Tsien. We landed beside the Grand Canal and set our pumps at
>   the edge of the ice -'